# Widget Layout with layout_weight and Images give diffrent height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, image-scaling

I have problem with layout when I want have images with different width but this same height. When I use only images with this same width and height, layout_weight work properly. But when I add images with different width, it is not OK. The height on dot is different.

Images have size: 141x191 [zero], and 28x191 [dot].

Images: [screen shot both layout. with one size images, and second with dot and different height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjOg.png)

If you see problem is when I add dot, because the height is different. I try resolve this problem 2days :/

Code:

```
<LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


---------- 

Second

<LinearLayout    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="28" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/dot2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="141" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/zero" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I use only imageview, without linearlaout to each images, problem is this same.

Answer (score 0):

Using so much layoutweight is not a good idea... can you not make the zero and dot images of the same size?

Comment: i want create the clock. zero [and other] will be digital number[this same width]. dot, it's separations. like: 23:10 etc. only the difrent width create problem

Comment: I would not have used the layout to solve the problem, I would have just done custom drawing with matrix how each digits will be rendered. What you are trying to do is heavy duty.

Comment: hmmm, in matrix put all digits? but how with optymalizations? i don't want drain battery, or cpu

Comment: What I mean by matrix is a matrix grid like a 8x8 boolean array for example.

so a 8 might look like 
`00111100
11000011
11000011
00111100
11000011
11000011
00111100`

and then when you want to render the digit, you render corresponding matrix with images or x and 0

makes sense?

(don't know how to make that matrix look nice with new line.